# confirming jenkins build and then proceeding to actual build

Tags: jenkins

I have a parameterized build which accept string as parameter . I want to show user a message "empty string" in the form of alert box or simply showing "Not entered anything.Do you want to continue> with continue button below" if he click on build button without entering string in text box. If he enters the string then i will start my build . How i can achieve this ?
Any help would be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show any kind of prompt or popup to user after <kbd>Build</kbd> button is pressed.

You can use [**Validating String**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin) plugin to validate the input and show error message in red *before* the <kbd>Build</kbd> button is pressed, and if the user ignores the error and presses the button anyways, the build will fail.

Comment: Is there any plugin to validate checkbox and file reader ? I also need it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "to validate checkbox"

Comment: I mean i have build page on which there are several checkboxes. Each checkbox represent build for perticular platform. We are providing facility to user for selection of platforms to build on. But if user not select any platform then i want to show them alert box showing please selected at least one paltform .

Comment: For that, you will have to write a script as a build-step, that would check all values, and fail the build if requirements are not meant.